2nd gen Cloud function response size too large
I have a 2nd gen HTTP Python cloud function that queries a large Bigquery table and returns large amounts of data, like this:
from google.cloud import bigquery
import functions_framework


client = bigquery.Client()


@functions_framework.http
def qry_bq(request):

    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)

    df = client.query(qry).to_dataframe()
    return df.to_json()


Sometimes, when the returned results of the query are large, the response results in a 500 error with the error message:
Response size was too large. Please consider reducing response size.
I saw here that the HTTP response size is limited to 32GB. Are there any suggestions to circumvent this issue for my use case?

The typical solution for dealing with large datasets over an API is to implement pagination using that API.  The number of items in a "page" of data should be set to some reasonable maximum given the max size of the response you want to allow.  The API should then be designed to allow for a way for the client to specify which page of data to get, or specify a cursor that indicates which item of data should be at the start of the next batch of results.
